# @Section Scripts in VB.Net (ASP Razor) not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

Why does this not work in VB.NET?

```
 @Section Scripts
            <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo-grid-utilities/kendo-grid-filter-menu-sorter.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
     End Section
```

for scripts included on the page itself, script inclusion works, but only like this, with the @Section Scripts INSIDE the  tag:

```
<script>
    @Section Scripts

    function blah(parameter){
...
```

I have been forced to put the script tags inside @Section Content instead... after the on-page styles..

EDIT: It's a page used within a Kendo Window.

I am having issues with scripts not loading (only in IE!!) and I want to rule this out as a cause.

Comment: Have you tried bundling the scripts?

Comment: that is my next move!

Comment: Are you using a Template page? Make sure that 

@RenderSection("Scripts", required:=False)

 is included below where you load your jquery or other libraries

Comment: @RenderSection("Scripts", required:=False)  is there

Comment: It looks like only the first script gets loaded.. I get an error (Invalid character) coming from jquery.js ... I guess that stops the rest loading?

Comment: Daniel - if you want to write that up as an answer (Bundling), I will delete mine and mark yours as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I did comment on one of your previous posts too, maybe try the following rather:

```
@Section Scripts
            <script src="~/Scripts/kendo-grid-utilities/kendo-grid-filter-menu-sorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
End Section
```

Comment: That is what I have now with the bundling - see above.

Answer (score 0):

Bundling is the answer, at least for this part of the issue!

e.g. in BundleConfig

```
 bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/common").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/utility/script1.js",
                   "~/Scripts/utility/script2.js"))
```

and in the webpage

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/common")
```

Thank you to all!

Comment: You should probably provide the steps you took to resolve this. This answer doesn't _really_ help feature users viewing the question.